# JSP vs Facelets as view technology for JSF

Tags: xml, jsp, jsf, facelets, sax

I'm not 100% percent what's the difference between JSP and Facelets, when it comes to JSF view technology.
I searched on google and everybody explains the difference (some by just copying others) in the same way.
I want to know what is the difference if I have a JSP page (document style, with jsp:root, so no scriptlets) or a Facelets page, when a **reuqest comes in**, and when in RenderResponse **each JSF tag is executed**.
Also what's the difference between **ui:include** and **jsp:include**. I understand JSP/Servlet very good, but not that much the JSF internals.
Thanks, and I hope you won't see this question like all other JSP vs Facelets questions.

ps: a small fraction of response I found is that **Facelets isn't transformed in Java Servlet Class**, like JSPs are (which this makes it faster), **but instead uses a SAX parser**, which I don't understand what it does in its callback methods.

Comment: About `Facelets isn't transformed in Java Servlet Class`, JSF's controller is a Servlet in fact. The only thing I can say is Facelets are the standard for JSF 2.0 implementations, so, being JSF the JavaEE standard framework for the view part, it makes sense going with Facelets instead of JSP's in new projects. They are fully compatible with JSP's, but last ones have a different lifecycle and are evaluated before facelet tags.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that in JSP you code pages. In JSF you code components rather than pages. That's the main difference.

Comment: question is about Facelets (vs JSP)